# Convert composite values into columns in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Suppose I have a pandas dataframe as follow:

```
Category    col1    col2    value
  A          a        a        1
  A          a        b        2
  A          b        a        3
  A          b        b        4
  B          a        a        5
  B          a        b        6
  B          b        a        7
  B          b        b        8
```

Now I want to change the dataframe to the following format:

```
Category    aa    ab    ba    bb  
A            1     2     3     4
B            5     6     7     8
```

I tried several approaches but it didn't work. Does it exist a function to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join columns together with [`pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot.html):

```
df['new'] = df['col1'] + df['col2']
df1 = df.pivot('Category','new','value')
print (df1)
new       aa  ab  ba  bb
Category                
A          1   2   3   4
B          5   6   7   8
```

Or [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
df1 = df.set_index(['Category',df['col1'] + df['col2']])['value'].unstack()
print (df1)
          aa  ab  ba  bb
Category                
A          1   2   3   4
B          5   6   7   8
```

Last if need column from index:

```
df1 = df1.rename_axis(None, axis=1).reset_index()
print (df1)
  Category  aa  ab  ba  bb
0        A   1   2   3   4
1        B   5   6   7   8
```

---

If possible error:

> ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape

```
print (df)
  Category col1 col2  value
0        A    a    a      1
1        A    a    a      4
2        A    a    b      2
3        A    b    a      3
4        A    b    b      4
5        B    a    a      5
6        B    a    b      6
7        B    b    a      7
8        B    b    b      8
```

Then need [`DataFrame.pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html) with aggregate function, e.g. default `mean`:

```
df['new'] = df['col1'] + df['col2']
df = df.pivot_table(index='Category',columns='new',values='value', aggfunc='mean')
print (df)
new        aa   ab   ba   bb
Category                    
A         2.5  2.0  3.0  4.0
B         5.0  6.0  7.0  8.0
```